# How to scroll to the top of a ScrollView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have a ScrollView which i would like to scroll to the top of it every 30 seconds.
This is my xaml:

```
<ScrollView Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled" x:Name="alerts_scroll">
                <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding OVSAlerts}" 
                                x:Name="alerts">
                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                          .....
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>

            </ScrollView>
```

I have tried this code:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
{
    await alerts_scroll.ScrollToAsync(0, 0 , true);
});
```

Also tried it with the **Element** and **ScrollToPosition** overload. No success either.
I thought **0,0** is the way to go but it give me no scroll at all or just a few px. where there was much to scroll to the top.
Thanks

Comment: I have tested your code in my project and it worked when I removed the scrollview.

Answer (score 1):

a `CollectionView` is inherently scrollable.  You do not need to nest it inside of a `ScrollView`.